# Why new Java 8 images published by OpenJDK are no longer Alpine based but Debian 10(Buster) based?

Tags: java, alpine-linux, debian-buster

I am browsing newest images published by OpenJDK: https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/8u252-jre-slim-buster/images/sha256-01dfdeac537b9d9adcb2399028fba063733a77186c5264e6b059987002c0e48c?context=explore all of them switchedt

all of the new Java 8 images are using Debian based, is there any official statement that OpenJDK moved from Alpine towards Debian and why?

Why new Java 8 images published by OpenJDK are no longer Alpine based but Debian 10(Buster) based?

Comment: I don't think anyone which is not related with the openjdk team can answer this.

Comment: Please note that the OpenJDK project does not publish docker images. This is a docker image created by the docker community (under sponsorship of Docker, Inc), not by the OpenJDK project. See also https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk and [Official Images on Docker Hub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/)

Comment: @Lino how to reach them?

Comment: @Yoda I guess that the openjdk has an official support channel, be it mail or something like that. You'd have to search their official website though

Comment: I don't think this question is related to java or JDK. Also you can create your own Docker images the way you want. There are just way too many ways anyone can package JDK into docker image.

Comment: By the way, you can still pull their alpine based images using tag `openjdk:<version>-alpine`. It is described on their official page https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk?tab=description  and https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/openjdk/README.md

Comment: You contact the docker community maintaining this image through https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues

Comment: The [Portola Project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/portola/) is ***porting*** Java to [musl libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271603/how-to-find-newest-version-of-openjdk-8-and-its-distributor#comment108393780_61271603). Alpine is based on musl (as I've told you before). Currently Java requires glibc. Adding glibc to Alpine is possible (and what those docker images currently do). If you do that, it negates the advantage of running Alpine (which is small because it uses musl, not glibc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On May 2019, OpenJDK Dockerhub images have shifted to using official, certified OpenJDK binaries, rather than distro OpenJDK packages:
https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/pull/322

These binaries are vanilla upstream [OpenJDK builds provided by AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/upstream.html), tested and backed by RedHat. The binaries are glibc based, so while they are compatible with Debian, they are not Alpine Linux compatible.

**Background:**

Until May 2019, OpenJDK had both Debian and Alpine images, using the packaged OpenJDK versions and installed through the distribution package managers, `apt` for Debian,  `apk` for Alpine. The Debian and Alpine packages are built and maintained by the community, and are such are not verified to the extent of commercial enterprise OpenJDK builds - for example, they are usually not [JCK](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/) certified.

Then, there has been an incident in which a Debian packaged OpenJDK 8 pre-release build has found its way into the official OpenJDK 8 docker image. The issue was initially reported in this thread:
https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2019-May/009330.html

After that, it was decided that OpenJDK images will only use official, JCK tested builds, to have one "source of truth". This decision affected both Debian and Alpine images.

**Alpine OpenJDK support:**

The OpenJDK project does not have official support for Alpine Linux, yet. Alpine Linux builds upon [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/), which is a minimal and strict POSIX implementation, and is generally not compatible with the standard [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). OpenJDK porting for musl libc is under development under OpenJDK's project [Portola](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/portola/).

Alpine Linux [`openjdk8`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/openjdk8) packages are provided by [IcedTea](https://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page). The IceaTea project provides builds for OpenJDK 6, 7 and 8, and was started back when OpenJDK was not fully open sourced yet. These builds are community made, and are not official OpenJDK builds. Moreover, the Alpine Linux OpenJDK 8 IcedTea builds are built from source by Alpine maintainers. Therefore, these builds cannot be considered as production ready, certified builds of OpenJDK.

Moving away from Alpine images had a large impact on the Alpine Java ecosystem; many projects have moved their images away from Alpine since, which is unfortunate. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/pull/322).